# Confused on SQL assignment

Tags: mysql

We are doing a database query in class. And it's using relational keys. I don't know how to get the query to run. Here is what is says.

> For each movie, list its number and title, along with the number and name of the actors who appeared in it.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT `Movie`,`Movie_ID`,`ActorNum` FROM `Movies` 
Union
Select Actor.Fname, Actor.Lname FROM Actor
;
```

Comment: please post your table schema

Comment: You cannot use the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) operator like that. You have to use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). If you get stuck, read the error messages (if any) and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what all the column names are but if ActroName would be the actors name would this be what you are looking for?

```
SELECT Movies.Movie, 
       Movies.Movie_ID, 
       Movies.ActroNum, 
       Actor.ActroName 
FROM Movies
JOIN Actor ON 
          Actor.ActroNum = Movies.ActroNum
```